# additional results/note in search

Tags: php, database, search

wondering if it is possible, that when you search a list of pages and data from a site, if you can not only order them in the most related first, but to also show a value.

ex. you search for data you previously entered regarding lemonade you sold. you keep track of multiple factors like "time of day, temperature, month, etc." you want to know about how much you are going to sell a week later, so you punch in values to "time of day, temperature, month, etc."

In theory, i am hoping to be able to bring up all entered data in accordance to relevance, and it shows you an estimate of what you will sell based on previous records. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It would require an algorithm. i wont write all the code, but i wont mind giving some guidance :). 
The html to fetch the data would be the same as the html to set the data, except it will call a seperate .php script.

The example below can be used for guidance. It uses only **temperature** to calculated predicted sales:

```
//get todays temperature from form, and query database for all temperatures
$todaysTemp = $_POST['temperature'];
$tempRange = 20;    //each temperature in the table must be within this range of todaysTemp to be included in calculation
$result = $connection->query("SELECT temperature, sales FROM myTable");

//calculate average temperature by adding this temp to total, then diving by total rows included
$temp_sales_array = array();
foreach($result as $row){
    if( abs($todaysTemp - $row['temperature']) < tempRange){
        $temp_sales_array[$row['temperature']] = $row['sales'];
    }
}

//calculate predicted sales, by getting array value thats closest to todays temperature
$closest=key($temp_sales_array[0]);
foreach($temp_sales_array as $row){
    if( abs($todaysTemp - key($row)) < closest ){
        closest = key($row);
        $predicted_sales = $row;
    }
}

//show predicted sales
echo $predicted_sales;
```